# Magento 2.2 login page Element 'action', attribute 'ifvalue': The attribute 'ifvalue' is not allowed

Tags: debugging, magento2.2.0, developer-mode

In developer mode my login page is displaying the following error:

Magento 2.2.0 login page Element 'action', attribute 'ifvalue': The attribute 'ifvalue' is not allowed

Can anyone guide me in debugging this error? Where to look?

In production mode pages are working fine.

> Update 1:

When checked all the layout files I have found the following lines in different files where this '**ifvalue**' attribute is mentioned:

- `<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="marketplace/profile_settings/seller_profile_display" ifvalue="1">`
- `<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="socialsignup/sociallogin/enabled" ifvalue="1">`
- `<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="socialsignup/sociallogin/enabled" ifvalue="1">`

I guess this code is to set template if config value is 1. I am trying to figure out the right way to achieve this.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Not yet, but I have just removed [ifvalue="1"] and after running setup upgrade this issue was gone.